# Multiple timezone Laravel how to show correct time with time picker

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

I'm trying to implement multiple timezone in laravel. I have already JS which collect users Timezone and successfully stored in 'timezone' column in Users table.

I have a view blade where user can choose the date and the time to schedule when their campaign will be sent. Im struggling to pass the users timezone to be shown in the view ("h:i A",). At the moment shows the timezone from config/app.php which is in my case 'Europe/Amsterdam'.

Here is the part of the view with bootstrap datepicker and time.

```
<div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-md-5">
                                   <label for="" class="form-label">Start Sending:</label>
                                   <br>
                                   <input type="radio" name="send_at" @if(old('send_at') != "now") checked @endif value="now" id="send-now">
                                   <label for="send-now">Now</label><br>
                                   <input type="radio" @if($mailing && strtotime($mailing->send_at) > time()) checked @endif name="send_at" value="latter" id="send-latter">
                                   <label for="send-latter">Later</label><br>
                                   
                                   <?php 
                                       $ts = time();
                                       if($mailing && !old('send_date')) {
                                           $ts = strtotime($mailing->send_at);
                                       } elseif(old('send_date')) {
                                           $ts = strtotime(old('send_date') .' '. old('send_time'));
                                       }
                                   ?>
                                           
                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-6 pb-20">
                                           <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" name="send_date" value="{{ date("m/d/Y", $ts) }}">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                           
                                           <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                           <input type="text"  name="send_time"  value="{{ date("h:i A", $ts) }}" id="timepicker" class="form-control input-small">
                                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                                           <span class="input-group-addon">CET</span>

                                       </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div> 
                           </div>
```

I tried to add this kind of attribute in my model but Im not sure which arguments I should add here to get time shown correctly in the view:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) 
    {      
       $timezone = optional(auth()->user())->timezone ?? config('app.timezone');
       return Carbon::parse($value)->timezone($timezone);
    }
```

Here is the method from the model. I also need to convert time in the Send_At column If user use Australian time for example it will write exact Australian time in the database but campaign will be send 8 hours latter since time different and because my database is setup to European time. Im not sure how to achieve to convert time in that column.

```
protected $table = 'mailings';
   

   public function saveMailing(User $user, $data)
   {
       $subscribers = isset($data['subscribers']) && $data['subscribers'] ? $data['subscribers'] : null;
       $subscribersIds = array();
       
       if($subscribers) {
           $subscribersArr = explode(",", $subscribers);
           if(count($subscribersArr) > 0) {
               foreach ($subscribersArr as $sid) {
                   if($sid > 0) {
                       $subscribersIds[$sid] = $sid;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       $this->user_id = $user->id;
       $this->promo_id = $data['promo_id'];
       $this->mailinglist_id = $data['mailinglist_id'] > 0 ? $data['mailinglist_id'] : null;
       $this->subject = $data['subject'];
       $this->body = $data['body'];
       $this->send_at = $data['send_at'];
       $this->type = isset($data['type']) && $data['type'] == 'reminder' ? 'reminder' : 'notification';
       $this->subscribers = count($subscribersIds) > 0 ? implode(",", $subscribersIds) : null;
       
       $this->save();
   }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest solution would be to add the following to the `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can try replacing `time()` with laravel's helper method - `now(UTC)` and provide the timezone as a parameter.

Also, change `strtotime` as in the following:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mailing->send_at, 'UTC')
    ->setTimezone('Africa/Lagos')
```

Comment: Hi Faruk. I added my Model in the post. This work in boot (). Do you know how to convert time in Send_At column? If user use Australian time for example it writes exact Australian time in the database but campaign will be send 8 hours latter because my database is setup to European time. Im not sure how to achieve to convert time in that column. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean your server is set to European time? Because your db's timezone shouldnt matter as long as the timezone settings in your app are to your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

you can change datetime format by following

[Carbon doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
return Carbon::parse($value)->format('g:i A')->timezone($timezone);
```